# Formula Required when two criteria match in both the sheet/table

Tags: excel

[image: Table]

I need to match two criteria in different sheet/table and update the comment.
See the table for more information.

If the two criteria in sheet 1 exactly match with sheet 2 (with 2 criteria) - Comment as Cleared

If only one as Policy number then it should mention it as different date and so on.

Note: There will be same policy number will be existed with different date

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula with ctrl+Shift+Enter:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3&B3,$E$3:$G$5&F3:F5,3,FALSE),"Data Not Available in Table 2")
```

Comment: No it is not working. I'm getting everything as data not available in table 2. I need to match date and policy number in both the sheet.

Comment: Hay!!! It's working (I haven't tried using ctrl+shift+enter) but the only one problem is that if I it cleared in different date then it should show as "Cleared in different date" but it is showing as "Data not available in table 2"

Comment: Please provide the other tables to check

Comment: I have provided both the tables (table 1 and 2). I have given comments in column c and g